# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'devices' of undefined in ionic 4 Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, interface

I have a class called MyDevicesPage which controls a page i am trying to manipulate the res object and then pass it to updateDevicesToServer method of DataService for further actions. the code compiles fine but in run time it throws an error **ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'devices' of undefined**

here are the class and associated interfaces

```
export class MydevicesPage implements OnInit {  

  devices : Array<deviceInterface>
  constructor(private deviceService : DeviceService,private route:  ActivatedRoute,private router: Router, private authenticationService : AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.deviceService.getDevices().then((res : devicesInterface) => {
      if(res){        
        let data : ResUpdateDevices
        data.devices = res;
        this.devices = res.devices;        

        data.token = this.authenticationService.getToken();

        this.deviceService.updateDevicesToServer(data).subscribe(res => {
          console.log(res)
        },err=>{
          console.log(err)
        });
      } 
    })
  }

  goto_device(ssid : String, name : String){
    this.router.navigate(['members','device',ssid,name])
  }

}
```

**ResUpdateInterface Interface**

```
export interface ResUpdateDevices{
    devices : devicesInterface
    token : string
}
```

**DeviceInterface Interface**

```
export interface deviceInterface {
  ssid : String,
  name : String
}
```

**DevicesInterface Interface**

```
export interface devicesInterface {
  devices : Array<deviceInterface>  
}
```

*Console Logging res gives this*

```
{devices : [{ssid:"ssid", name :"name"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving this error because you are not initialising your `data` object before trying to assign `data.devices = res;`. I suggest the following update:

```
let data: ResUpdateDevices = {
    devices: res,
    token: this.authenticationService.getToken(),
};
this.devices = res.devices;
```